# How can I send messages in Gmail using python?

Tags: python, email, gmail

I am completely new to this topic but thought it would make a good project. I want to take input from the user and message it to a contact of my choice.

```
msginput=input("What would you like to send?: ")
recipientinput=input("To whom would you like to send this message?:")
def sending(msginput, recipientinput):
  #the function here
```

you can change this code however you like but this is just how I imagined it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Google Apps Script to automatically send an email using input and contact information. You can find more information in this article https://www.codementor.io/@olatundegaruba/google-apps-script-automated-emails-m2m0ojq9v